# finding the subsequence of strings in c# urjent

Tags: string, subsequence

Alice has two strings, initial and goal. She can remove some number of characters from initial, which will give her a subsequence of that string. A string with no deletions is still considered a subsequence of itself. Given these two strings, can you find the minimum number of subsequences of initial that, when appended together, will form goal?

Comment: Stating your homework assignment isn't really asking a question.

Answer (score -1):

```
function minimumConcat(initial, goal) {

   let result = 0;
   let pattern = ''
   let count1 = Array.apply(null, Array(26)).map(Number.prototype.valueOf, 0);
   let count2 = Array.apply(null, Array(26)).map(Number.prototype.valueOf, 0);

   initial.split('').forEach(c => {
     pattern = pattern + c
   });
   pattern = "^[" + pattern + "]*$"

   if (!RegExp(pattern).test(goal)) return -1

   for (let i = 0; i < initial.length; i++) {
        count1[initial.charCodeAt(i) - 97]++;
   }

   for (let i = 0; i < goal.length; i++) {
        count2[goal.charCodeAt(i) - 97]++;
   }

   for (let i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        result += Math.abs(count1[i] - count2[i]);
   }

   return result;
}
var initial = readline();
var goal = readline();

print(minimumConcat(initial, goal));
```